# PST and AKST Time Zone Error

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, time, timezone, equals

When I run this code below the **PST** and **AKST** timezones are never run... Both of these are run perfectly:

```
NSTimeZone *pacificTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"PST"];
NSTimeZone *alaskaTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"AKST"];
```

But neither one of these are run:

```
}else if ([local isEqual: pacificTimeZone]) {
    NSLog(@"Pacific");

} else if ([local isEqual: alaskaTimeZone]) {
    NSLog(@"Alaska");
```

Any suggestions?

```
    NSTimeZone *local = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    NSTimeZone *centralTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"CST"];
    NSTimeZone *easternTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"EST"];
    NSTimeZone *mountainTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"MST"];
    NSTimeZone *pacificTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"PST"];
    NSTimeZone *alaskaTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"AKST"];
    NSTimeZone *honoluluTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"HST"];

    NSLog(@"LOCAL TIME ZONE: %@", local);

    NSLog(@"CST TIME %@", centralTimeZone);
    NSLog(@"EST TIME %@", easternTimeZone);
    NSLog(@"MST TIME %@", mountainTimeZone);
    NSLog(@"PST TIME %@", pacificTimeZone);
    NSLog(@"AKST TIME %@", alaskaTimeZone);
    NSLog(@"HST TIME %@", honoluluTimeZone);


    if ([local isEqual: centralTimeZone])
    {
        NSLog(@"Central");

    } else if ([local isEqual: easternTimeZone]) {
        NSLog(@"Eastern");

    } else if ([local isEqual: mountainTimeZone]) {
        NSLog(@"Mountain");

    }else if ([local isEqual: pacificTimeZone]) {
        NSLog(@"Pacific");

    } else if ([local isEqual: alaskaTimeZone]) {
        NSLog(@"Alaska");

    } else if ([local isEqual: honoluluTimeZone]) {
        NSLog(@"Honolulu");

    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimeZone/timeZoneWithAbbreviation:):

> In general, you are discouraged from using abbreviations except for unique instances such as "UTC" or "GMT". Time Zone abbreviations are not standardized and so a given abbreviation may have multiple meanings - for example, "EST" refers to Eastern Time in both the United States and Australia

Instead, use [`timeZoneWithName`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimeZone/timeZoneWithName:).  Supported time zones are from the [IANA TZ database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database), and you can find a list of them [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

The most common zones for the United States are as follows:

```
Alaska   = "America/Anchorage"
Hawaii   = "Pacific/Honolulu"
Pacific  = "America/Los_Angeles"
Arizona  = "America/Phoenix"
Mountain = "America/Denver"
Central  = "America/Chicago"
Eastern  = "America/New_York"
```

Comment: for Hawaii its Pacific/Honolulu